# Could not load file or assembly, the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio, json.net, nuget, azure-functions, alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating an Azure Function to act as a backend for an Alexa skill.

All I've done so far in Visual Studio:

1. File -> New Azure Functions project
2. Add new Azure Function
3. Add AlexaSkillsKit.NET with NuGet
4. Create a shell of a `Speechlet` implementation
5. Add the minimum code to the Azure Function to process the speechlet

When I compile, I get an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But according to NuGet in Visual Studio, it's not trying to use 7.0.0.0, it's using 9+. I've tried updating and downgrading the JSON.net package. I've tried Clean/Rebuild/restarting from scratch.

I thought that maybe assembly binding might be the answer, but there's no Web.config or App.config in an Azure Functions project.

What am I missing? How do I get rid of this error?

Speechlet code:

```
public class MySpeechlet : SpeechletBase, ISpeechletWithContextAsync
{
    public Task<SpeechletResponse> OnIntentAsync(IntentRequest intentRequest, Session session, Context context)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<SpeechletResponse> OnLaunchAsync(LaunchRequest launchRequest, Session session, Context context)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task OnSessionStartedAsync(SessionStartedRequest sessionStartedRequest, Session session, Context context)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task OnSessionEndedAsync(SessionEndedRequest sessionEndedRequest, Session session, Context context)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Azure Function:

```
public static class MyFunction
{
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        var speechlet = new MySpeechlet();
        return await speechlet.GetResponseAsync(req);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does one of your dependencies has Newton v7 as sub-dependency?

Comment: No, that's what I meant by " according to NuGet in Visual Studio, it's not trying to use 7.0.0.0, it's using 9+". But let's suppose that's the case, what could I do about it?

Comment: Not much. You basically need to use the same versions of dependencies at the moment.

Comment: Hi @MatthewGroves looks  like the issue is with Alexaskills package. If we use version 1.5.2 I am able to build the solution. The error is thrown if we use 1.6.0 version.

Comment: Looks like v7 dependency is got from the Alexaskills package. Just did a fork from latest code. https://github.com/baskar3078/AlexaSkillsKit.NET/blob/master/.nuget/AlexaSkillsKit.Lib.nuspec

Comment: The  Alexaskills package have a dependency `Newtonsoft.Json (>= 7.0.1)`, have you reference another version nuget Newtonsoft.Json 9.0+ on your project? If yes, how about replace it with version 7.0.1?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I don't think any other packages have a Json dependency, but let's suppose they do. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Function 1.X host itself depends on Newtonsoft.Json 9 :
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/v1.x/src/WebJobs.Script/packages.config#L60

And this is the DLL that will be loaded, it a known and very annoying issue with azure functions:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/992

If Alexaskills depends specifically on 7 and will not work with 9, then you are stuck I'm afraid, maybe create a pull request on Alexaskills.

As a side note, if you have created your Azure Function with recent tooling,your project should have a dependency on Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions, which at least makes these dependencies explicit.